# docker size used is bigger than total size of actual images

Tags: docker

I am using docker on windows, and after stopping and running an image several times, the size of space used in disk keeps increasing.

When I run `docker system df`, the result is :

```
TYPE            TOTAL       ACTIVE          SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images          1           0               28.42GB             28.42GB (100%)
Containers      0           0               0B                  0B
Local Volumes   0           0               0B                  0B
Build Cache     0           0               0B                  0B
```

But when I check Docker → Settings → Advanced → Disk image max size : 208 GB (152.53 GB used).

Comment: Need more information. What's in the dockerfile?